# "Allow this device to wake the computer" option disabled

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, wake-on-lan

Why in our new Dell R515 Rack Server the Broadcom BCM5716C NetXtreme II GigE device has the "Allow this device to wake the computer" option always disabled? We have enabled hibernation and need to wake up this machine using WakeOnLan.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think hibernation has anything to do with the power management options of the NIC.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have not properly set the BIOS settings, which are also required for WOL to work.

Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN

and this: http://lifehacker.com/348197/access-your-computer-anytime-and-save-energy-with-wake+on+lan